# Exposing webserver in minikube to the internet

Tags: networking, kubernetes, webserver, minikube

I am trying to expose service to the internet from minikube cluster.

I have installed the minikube using docker on server with address `192.168.1.110` and the cluster installed itself with `192.168.49.2` address. However I want to use address ending with 110 for outside world.

When I deploy deployment and then service

```
xxx:~$ kubectl get services
NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE
kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP        3d4h
webserver    NodePort    10.106.223.172   <none>        80:32087/TCP   9m54s
xxx:~$ kubectl get deployments
NAME        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
webserver   3/3     3            3           4h42m
```

and then write `kubectl port-forward services/webserver 8090:80`

I can finally access it on `192.168.1.110:8090`.

Is there any other way for me to deploy the web server to desired address without manually forwarding the port each time ? I want to set it out as production solution so this is not acceptable.

Comment: In my case I am using this: `kubectl port-forward services/app-web 8080:80 --address 0.0.0.0`, as I want to provide svc externally, whereas if I don't provide the `--address` the `kubectl` listens on `127.0.0.1`.
Still looking for a better way.

Answer (score -2):

**Please note that Minikube is meant for local usage. It is only using a single VM, which does not scale or allow for high availability.**

Anyhow, regarding exposing services externally, please consider one of the following techniques:

1. Expose your service on the IP of the worker nodes via a [Node Port Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).
2. Expose your service on the IP of a Loadbalancer via a [Loadbalancer Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

For the latter option, best make use of an [Ingress Controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/).

Comment: I don't think this helps at all. Question is specific to Minikube, whereas you provide the Kubernetes specific answer. The OP already already reached the outer layer of Kubernetes by using by using NodePort service, now the question is how to go outside of Minikube which maybe a docker container, VM etc. and serve on your chosen host interface.